# How to make a series chart with date in X-axis in dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am using dc.js V3.2.1 and crossfilter. I am trying to make a series chart with a date dimension and facing trouble making a chart with date in X-axis and the count in Y-axis .  In my Output the X-axis is not displaying as a date.

I need two groups as Admin and Agent in the agent column of my data and with two line in series chart — one line as Admin group and another line as Agent line in the chart.

My sample data:

```
create_time,agent 
2017-01-01,Admin 
2017-01-02,Admin 
2017-01-02,Admin    
2017-01-02,Admin 
2017-01-01,Agent 
2017-01-02,Agent 
2017-01-03,Admin    
2017-01-03,Admin 
2017-01-03,Admin 
2017-01-03,Agent 
2017-02-01,Admin    
2017-02-01,Agent 
2017-02-01,Agent 
2017-02-02,Admin 
2017-02-02,Admin    
2017-02-03,Agent 
2017-02-03,Agent 
2017-03-01,Admin 
2017-03-01,Admin    
2017-03-01,Admin 
2017-03-01,Admin 
2017-03-01,Agent 
2017-03-01,Agent    
2017-03-01,Agent 
2017-04-01,Admin 
2017-04-01,Admin 
2017-04-01,Admin    
2017-04-01,Admin 
2017-04-01,Agent 
2017-04-01,Agent
```

This is my code:

```
<div id="test"></div>

<script src="./static/lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./static/lib/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./static/lib/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
  <script src="./static/lib/js/d3.js"></script>
  <script src="./static/lib/js/dc.js"></script>
  <script src="./static/lib/js/queue.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var chart = new dc.seriesChart("#test");

    d3.csv("static/data/agent.csv").then(function(agent) {
        var mycrossfilter = crossfilter(agent);
        var all = mycrossfilter.groupAll();

        agent.forEach(function(x) {
               if(x.gender == 'Admin') {
                  x.newdata = 1;
               } else {
                  x.newdata = 2;
               }
            });

           var minDate = d3.min(agent, function(d){ return d.create_time; });
           var maxDate = d3.max(agent, function(d){ return d.create_time; });

            var hwDimension = mycrossfilter.dimension(function(data) { 
               return [data.agent, data.create_time];
            });
            var hwGroup = hwDimension.group().reduceCount();

        chart
         .width(800)
         .height(600)
         .chart(function(c) { 
            return dc.lineChart(c).interpolate('cardinal').evadeDomainFilter(true);
         })
         .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
         .elasticY(true)
         .brushOn(false)
         .xAxisLabel("Height")
         .yAxisLabel("Count")
         .dimension(hwDimension)
         .group(hwGroup)
         .seriesAccessor(function(d) { return d.key[0];})
         .keyAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[1]; })
         .valueAccessor(function(d) { return +d.value; })
         .legend(dc.legend().x(350).y(500).itemHeight(13).gap(5).horizontal(1)
            .legendWidth(120).itemWidth(60));

      chart.render();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were doing everything right, but `d3.scaleTime` expects Date objects, so you need to convert the data:

```
    agent.forEach(function(x) {
      // ...
      x.create_time = new Date(x.create_time);
    });
```

I also removed the cardinal line interpolation because it does not work with this data (probably a bad idea in the first place). And it seemed to work after that, with dates shown in the X axis and everything.

[image: screenshot with formatted dates]

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/2jqfp1x4/20/).

#### Formatting the ticks

dc.js uses [d3-axis](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis) to draw the axes.

Use

```
chart.xAxis()
```

to retrieve the X axis, and [.tickFormat()](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickFormat) to set the format on the axis, passing a [d3.timeFormat](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#timeFormat).

In the above fiddle,

```
chart.xAxis().tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%Y-%m-%d'));
```

Comment: How do i format the date as in the data. For instance 2017-01-08 instead of jan 08

Comment: Updated answer with another section

Comment: Sorry to disturb you once again @Gordon, the labels are not in position in the x-axis. It's not showing the right position when i hover to the line.

Comment: I updated the fiddle and screenshot. It looks correct to me.

Comment: Is there any option to download the chart using dc.js

Comment: There's nothing included in the library to do this, however if you search for "download svg dc.js" or "download png dc.js" you will find ways to do this. It's the same as for D3 charts in general.